# WCSession on Apple Watch not work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I have XCode 7, iPhone6 with iOS 9.1, Apple Watch with WatchOS 2.0 (now I update to 2.0.1)

I try to make communication between Watch and iPhone.

On iPhone I init my singleton

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self.isConnectivityAvailable) {
        session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isConnectivityAvailable {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
        return [WCSession isSupported];
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //custom code
    (void)[AppConnectivityHandler instance]; //start App connectivity with Apple Watch
    return YES;
}
```

And it is all good

I process message like that

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull))replyHandler {
    LOG(@"receive message");
    NSString *request = message[kRequestKey];
    __block NSDictionary *reply = @{};
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([request isEqualToString:kRequestDayInfo]) {
            //formirate reply dictionary
        }
    });
    LOG(@"send reply");
    replyHandler(reply);
}
```

On my Watch I start load when called function in my main interface controller

```
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];
    if ([WatchConnectivityHandler instance].isConnectivityAvailable) {
        [[WatchConnectivityHandler instance] loadDayInfoWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error, WatchDayInfo * _Nullable dayInfo) {
             //code
        }];
    } else {
        //error
    }
}
```

My watch singleton

```
+ (nonnull instancetype)instance {
    static WatchConnectivityHandler *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [WatchConnectivityHandler new];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self.isConnectivityAvailable) {
        session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isConnectivityAvailable {
    return [WCSession isSupported];
}
- (void)loadDayInfoWithCompletion:(void(^ _Nonnull)( NSError * _Nullable error,  WatchDayInfo * _Nullable dayInfo))completion {
    [session sendMessage:@{kRequestKey : kRequestDayInfo} replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {
        NSLog(@"reply");
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@", replyMessage);
            //custom code
            completion(nil, /*custom object*/);
        });
    } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            completion(error, nil);
        });
    }];
}
```

So it work fine in first time and I get reply. But then I start a lot of errors like

```
Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7007 "WatchConnectivity session on paired device is not reachable." 


Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7014 "Payload could not be delivered."
```

I test on Watch, and it is often problem to get reply form my iPhone, it wait a long. But on iPhone I test, that when it get message from Watch, it very quick send reply, but I don't see that reply on Watch.

I need update my info every time when watch start my app. What the problem? Maybe I use not properly functions?

Answer (score -2):

Use transeruserinfo method instead of sendmessage and use didreceiveuserinfo method instead of didreceiveapplicationcontext.

Comment: Literally the exact opposite of this.